# Can a parameter of a function be NULL?

Tags: notation

Can a parameter of a function be NULL like in the example below?

$
 f_{AE}(t_x;i_1;i_2;p)= 
  \begin{cases} 
      \hfill \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=i_1}^{i_2} R_s(e_{c_k,t_x};a_k)}{p}    \hfill & \text{if $p \neq NULL \land R_s(e_{c_k,t_x};a_k)= p$} \\
      i_2 - i_1    \hfill & \text{if $p = NULL$} \\
  \end{cases}
$

Call option 1:

$f_{AE}(t_1;5;10)$

Call option 2:

$f_{AE}(t_1;5;10;5)$

Or do I need two completly separate functions with different parameters?

thx

Comment: Do you mean 0 (zero) or some non-numeric value? What domain is $p$ taken from?

Comment: NULL just implies that p does not have a value. I'm assuming this function has something to do with programming, where a variable can take on a NULL value (a funny way of saying it doesn't have a value).

Comment: I want to call the function like f(p1;p2;p3) and f(p1;p2;p3;p4). So sometime I want to use it with 3 and sometime I want to use it with 4 parameters. If I only use it with 3, the fourth parameter would be NULL. I think more like a programmer than a mathematician :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is YES, $p$ can take on the "value" NULL for the function you have provided.

For this function, you have allowed $p$ to contribute to the value if and only if it is not NULL. This implies that it has a value in your domain.

If $p$ is NULL, it should not contribute to the value of the function, because it wouldn't make any sense. Consider $$1+NULL = ???,$$ which is meaningless. Most computer languages interpret any math using NULL to equal NULL, so that

$$1+ NULL = NULL.$$

This is accounted for in your function by making the function equal $i_2-i_1$ when $p$ is NULL, which does not depend on $p$.

Comment: Ok sounds good. But than I have to call the function like f(1,4,NULL). I can't ignore the parameter like f(1,4)?

Comment: Yes, I would call it like f(1,4,NULL). You don't want to cause confusion by dropping the variable altogether. More importantly, if you are doing this on a computer, you will need to tell the computer that p is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

The inputs to a function can come from any set you like. There is nothing wrong with saying $p$ belongs to say, the set

$$\{\text{NULL}, 5,\}$$

But of course, care is needed to make sure you have a well-defined function.

[edit] I see from the comments that you don't just want it to be NULL, you want to completely omit the parameter.

You *can* do this if you tell your audience that you are doing it, **but** it is highly non-standard. This is because mathematicians have been taught to curry :) e.g. $A$ is a matrix/linear map, and $A(x)$ is a vector.

Comment: Haha ok thanks. So you mean I should rename the function because A is a matrix?

Comment: No, let me try a better example. Say we have a function $A : ℝ \times ℝ → ℝ$. If you give it only one input, $x$, then one would normally think of $A(x) : ℝ → ℝ$. i.e. we also think of $A$ as the curried function $A:ℝ → (ℝ → ℝ)$. This function takes in a single input, and gives you a **function** $ℝ→ℝ$. This is very different behaviour from what you were asking it to do. In mathematics, you can do whatever you want as long as you define it beforehand. But I think it will catch a few people off-guard.

Comment: @Stev an example that is like yours is
$$ f:ℝ\times(ℝ∪\{\}) → ℝ,\ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} xy & y ≠ \\ π & y=\end{cases}$$and then we already have one common interpretation, 
$$ f(x) : ℝ ∪ \{ \}→ℝ ,\ f(x)(y) =  \begin{cases} xy & y ≠ \\ π & y=\end{cases}$$
So to also define $f(x) := f(x,)∈ℝ $ will require you to state explicitly and carefully what you are doing.

Comment: Ok, got it :) Thank you very much for your efforts

Comment: I'm just happy to use  in a serious answer. :)

Comment: +1 for the  :D (and the good example, I suppose, but mostly for the )